# What is the name of this thorny plant?

Tags: botany, species-identification

Location: South India

Month: June

Tree:

[image]

Leaf:

[image]

Its Flower:

[image: description here]

EDIT:
For avoid confusion about ID this species, I even added its **flower** now.

Answer (score 6):

Your tree appears to be from the Genus *Dichrostachys*.

It has several species, quiet a number of them have been reported only in Madagascar.

There are two species found in India, *D. santapaui* and *D. cinerea.*

---

**How have I reached this plant?**

1. The leaves of your plant are bipinnately compound. They gave me the impression of *Mimosa pudica*.

   <sup>Of course it is not one. *Mimosa pudica* become creepers with time
   and have short and thin prickly thorns.</sup>
2. Resemblance of an unknown organism with a known one can indicate shared derived character(s) ([Synapomorphy](http://ib.berkeley.edu/courses/ib160/h2.html)), meaning they can be related.

   <sup>Google's algorithm is often able to trace this relation. [Look at the keywords I had used](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=mimosa%20yellow%20flower%20south%20india&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw5PTM3rrUAhXEpY8KHQ5VDV0Q_AUIBigB&biw=1366&bih=635#imgrc=RlQ0SXlJTilEfM:). If it doesn't one needs to experiment with the [keyworks](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=mimosa%20yellow%20flower%20south%20india&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw5PTM3rrUAhXEpY8KHQ5VDV0Q_AUIBigB&biw=1366&bih=635#tbm=isch&q=hanging+long+pink+yellow+fabaceae+flower+india&imgrc=lFTw7SjQE1NeOM:), note the word Fabaceae, it is the family to which *[Mimosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimosa_pudica)* belongs.</sup>
3. Wikipedia  often is just the right place to start one's research.

   The description of [*Dichrostachys cinerea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichrostachys_cinerea) is what I checked next, after having ascertained that is found in India.

> Dichrostachys cinerea is a tree **characterized by bark on young branches**, dark grey-brown fissures on older branches and stems and smooth on the spines.
>
> They typically grow up to 7 metres (23 ft) in height and **have strong *alternate* thorns**, generally up to **8 cm (3.1 in) long**.
>   Flowers of the Dichrostachys cinerea are characteristically in **bicoloured cylindrical** [spikes](http://theseedsite.co.uk/inflorescences.html) that resemble Chinese lanterns and are 6–8 cm long and fragrant.
>
> The species tends to grow in rainforest zones.In India, it can occur in dry deciduous forest.

4. Every thing fits well upto Genus [*Dichrostachys*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichrostachys).

> Dichrostachys is an *Old World* genus of legumes in the Fabaceae family.
>
> Their [Acacia-like](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=acacia&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-oNzk-rrUAhXBwI8KHe67DD0Q_AUIBigB&biw=1366&bih=635#imgdii=oj0psMZMmNzUHM:&imgrc=ayJgB4AjQBHKFM:) leaves are bi-pinnately compound.
>
> Unlike Acacia their thorns are ***hardened branchlets*** rather than modified stipules. They are native from Africa to Australasia...

The next thing I exhaustively checked were the species under this
    genus. I checked their
    [locations](http://zipcodezoo.com/index.php/Dichrostachys_akataensis),
    out of all two species have only been reported in India; *D.
    santapaui and D. cinerea.*

<sub>The reason behind this unusual format is to show you  how to fish. I will leave the rest of the hard work of digging up the species to you .</sub>

---

**Few interesting facts about this genus:**

- Its name is derived from the Greek words dis (two), chroos (colour) and stachys (grain ear or spike), which in combination suggests their bi-colored inflorescences.

[image]

- *Dichrostachys cinerea*, known as Sicklebush, Bell *mimosa*, [Chinese lantern](http://www.chinaspree.com/images/pic-lanterns.jpg) tree or Kalahari Christmas tree (South Africa).
- *D. cinerea* is [used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichrostachys_cinerea#Uses) in Ayurveda.

Comment: Great answer! You know what they say *Give a man a fish, he'll eat for a day; teach a man how to fish, he'll eat for a lifetime*. By explaining how to find the name of a species on our own, you have taught me and the OP how to identify on our own. Brilliant job I say!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's

***Prosopis juliflora:***

[image]

It's popularily known in South India as சீமை கருவேல (translitered as:**Seemai karuvelam**). It's an invasive weed introduced in 1880.

It belongs to the Fabaceae family of plants. It flowers quickly after leaves form:

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: I added flowers also now.